# txt file from pc to arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I was not able to find any examples by googling so I thought I might ask help from here.

I have a txt file of n lines. Each line contains a blueprint for arduino uno to execute needed thing, for example flash a light. In my sript I want to "load" this file to UNO and go through this file line by line executing the steps.

I only found examples for this kind of thing for SD card usage.

For example: 
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FileRead
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=95303.0

However,  I don't have SD card nor can I get one at the moment. Is there a way to read this file directly from pc and save it as an array for UNO to use.

Comment: Is there a reason why using a serial connection won't work?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the operating system you use, you can "pipe" the file to serial port, reading it from the Arduino using `Serial` object. On Linux:

```
cat myfile > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Replace USB0 if necessary.

**EDIT:**

For windows you might use type command. Not  sure if extended COM ports (other than 1 and 2) will work.

```
type myfile > COM5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different approach, that is store the content of required txt file / just the values to the EEPROM of the arduino.

The size of text that can be stored is minimal.The size of EEPROM solely depends on the Arduino used for e.g Mega has 4KB of EEPROM(One of the biggest), UNO has 1KB.This can be extended too as far as I know.

You can look into eeprom examples here -

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM

Its very easy to understand, just looks fuzzy and hard in the beginning.

There are other methods like using a SD card as you mentioned since that is not an option EEPROM is next best bet
Hope it helps.